# Using C# I want to create a bar chart that shows the count of each value in an excel column

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel sheet of raw data.  Using C# I would like to create a bar chart in excel of each value in one specific column (column c) and the number of times the value shows up.  I think I need to programmatically need to create a pivot chart in order to do this properly, but am unsure if this is the best way, and finding a good learning resource on how to properly implement it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Low quality/minimal effort questions attract likewise answers - https://danlb.blogspot.com/2014/06/excel-graphs-with-epplus.html

Comment: Using visual studio? if your using winforms theres a ready made chart thats easy to work with, its what i use for my forex app, and the candle chart is pretty easy to set up.